# Div em cima de imagem

Tags: html, posicionamento, css

estou a tentar colocar uma div em cima da imagem, essa div vai ser um container branco com uma certa altura e largura, dentro dessa container, vai conter um titulo e um paragrafo.

Abaixo vos deixo a seccao onde quero fazer esse tal container, a div tem o nome de "info-container". Eu consegui colocar o texto em cima da imagem, mas o container branco que estou a tentar criar, não aparece de maneira nenhuma.

HTML:

```
<section class="section-artists">
          <div class="row">
          <h1>SEE YOUR TOP ARTISTS</h1>
        </div>


            <ul class="artists-showcase Clearfix">

                <li>
                    <figure class="artist-photo">
                        <img src="img/logic.jpg" alt="Logic">
                        <div class="info-container">
                        <h4>LOGIC</h4>
                        <p>Twitter-API</p>
                        </div>
                    </figure>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <figure class="artist-photo">
                        <img src="img/avicci.jpg" alt="Avicci">                        
                        <div class="info-container">
                        <h4>LOGIC</h4>
                        <p>Twitter-API</p>
                        </div>
                    </figure>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <figure class="artist-photo">
                        <img src="img/ed_sheeran.jpg" alt="Ed Sheeran">
                        <div class="info-container">
                        <h4>LOGIC</h4>
                        <p>Twitter-API</p>
                        </div>
                    </figure>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <figure class="artist-photo">
                        <img src="img/eminem.jpg" alt="Eminem">
                        <div class="info-container">
                        <h4>LOGIC</h4>
                        <p>Twitter-API</p>
                        </div>
                    </figure>
                </li>

            </ul>
      </section>
```

CSS:

```
.section-artists {
    padding: 0;
} 

.artists-showcase {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block; /* Alinhamento centro */
    width: 110%;  /* Alinhamento centro */
    margin-left: -5%;  /* Alinhamento centro e full width */
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 5%; 

}


.artists-showcase li {
    display: block;
    transform: skewX(-10deg);
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
}


.artist-photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;

}




.artist-photo img {
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 150%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.18) skewX(10deg); /* reverte o skew para a imagem ficar reta */
    transform: skewX(10deg);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s, filter 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, filter 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s, filter 0.5s;  
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s, filter 0.5s;  
}


//*.artist-photo img:hover {
//    opacity: 1;
//    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03) skewX(10deg);;
//    transform: scale(1.03) skewX(10deg);
//    filter: hue-rotate(250deg);
/*/




/* Container com texto e titulo */

.info-container {
    background: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: -20%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.info-container>h4 {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.info-container>p {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Tente colocar nela position absolute

Comment: O postion absolute vai permitir que o z-index trabalhe melhor

Comment: O  container branco continua não aparecendo atrás das letras mesmo com o position ablosute..

Comment: Ele não apareceu em momento algum, ou não está aparecendo atrás das letras como você quer? É que antes você disse que ele não estava aparecendo mesmo. Por que se ele estiver aparecendo, é melhor você definir um z-index para cada. Tipo, imagem, z-index 1, container z-index 2, texto z-index 3

Comment: Continua não aparecendo amigo...

Answer (score 0):

Fiz esse arquivo simplificado aqui e ele pode te ajduar,

Html:

```
<figure class="artist-photo">
    <img src="img/01.jpg" alt="Ed Sheeran">
    <div class="info-container">
     <h4>LOGIC</h4>
     <p>Twitter-API</p>
   </div>
 </figure>
```

CSS:

```
.artist-photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
   overflow: hidden;
```

}

```
 .info-container {
   position: absolute;
   background: #bf1e1e;
   width: 500px;
   height: auto;
   top: 50px;
   padding: 0;
   margin-bottom: -20%;
   z-index: 1;
 }
```

Desta forma deu certo aqui, você pode pegar esse exemplo e ir colocando seus outros CSS's nele e ver o que está dando conflito.

Comment: Hummm, aqui não funciona, não percebo..

Comment: Uai, aqui eu fiz um arquivo separado só com esses códigos que te enviei, pena que não dá para mandar print, pois aqui funcionou normalmente...

Comment: Pois, ai está o problema é o conflito que nao consigo solucionar, mas obrigado!

Comment: Aqui aparece a foto, depois o fundo, depois o texto. o Fundo está na lateral direita da imagem, um pouco acima e ocupa boa parte da imagem